# React Native on Ipad - Error - could not connect to development server

Tags: ios, ipad, reactjs, react-native

I'm using React-Native, when I run the AwesomeProject with Xcode and iPhone simulator everything works well, but when I connected my iPad and built the project on my iPad I receive an error on the iPad when the app starts:

> "Could not connect to development server. Ensure node server is
>   running. The operation couldn't be completed (NSURLErrorDomain error
>   -1004)".

I also ensured that the node package is running. I even restarted Xcode and started it all over with running npm start.

Could you please assist?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On your AppDelegate.m you have to update the `jsCodeLocation` and replace `localhost` with your machine ip address.

Either that or bundle the compiled source into your application, which is commented as option 2 on `AppDelegate.m` as well. You download the compiled code, and add it to your Xcode project.

Comment: Thank you! it is working very well. I don't know exactly why but applying the solution mentioned on the github issue below ruined hot reload.

Comment: I'm using react-native and deco, but I don't do too much mobile development. Is it bad practice to edit the .m files when I'm using those tools? Either way, this worked. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try to take a look here for the solution:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/240#issuecomment-86977126

Answer (score 4):

Another potential issue which can cause the exact same error is App Transport Security (ATS) in iOS9--this happened to me, even though everything else was set up correctly.  See my description and solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34880394/2397068.

Answer (score 4):

I have prepared a small instruction which will help to solve this problem.

When your application cannot connect to the server, you will see the message like this:

[image]

Open a file AppDelegate.m in your Xcode project and look for

`jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];`

You have to replace this address with your local address.

[image]

To look up your local IP address in Mac OS X open Terminal application (located in /Applications/Utilities) and type `ipconfig getifaddr en1` for wireless, or `ipconfig getifaddr en0` for ethernet.

[image]

You can check It in browser. And you will see React Native Debugger page

[image]

Just replace `localhost` in AppDelegate.m with your IP address. `localhost` to `192.168.1.100` in my case.

[image]

Run your application in Xcode again.

Comment: Your solution did not work for me. Get error "nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 42 Connection has no connected handler"

Comment: 1) Xcode menu -> Product -> Edit Scheme 
2) Environment Variables -> Add -> Name: "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE", Value:"disable"
3) Run your app again!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just had a very old version of node.js installed (version 0.8.6).  After updating node.js to version 0.12.2, the default project that `react-native init AwesomeProject` created worked perfectly.